# files disappear when I run mv command

Tags: mv

Dears,

I use the below command to move files

mv *.gz directoryname

but directory name has spell mistake and the file with directory name has been generated with unknown format. And I lost my file.

How can I get them back? is there anyway to get them from the directoryname which is generated while running mv command.

Please let me know if you want me to more clear on this.

Thanks

Comment: Crossposted here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260577/files-dissapear-when-i-run-mv-command

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on Unix & Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260577/files-dissapear-when-i-run-mv-command

Comment: you are missing a / behind directoryname to prevent unwanted moving of the gz to that directoryname.

Answer (score -2):

If you use those command, the `*.tgz` files should go to `directoryname`, even if `directoryname` didn't exist, system will automaticly create directory with your mispelled-`directoryname`, try to find your file using

```
cd directoryname
ls -la | grep tgz
```

if your desired file didn't there, maybe you can find it using `locate` or `whereis`

Hope that's help you, even a little.

Comment: `mv` will either rename (in the case that `*.tgz` expands to a single file) or exit with error `mv: target ‘directoryname’ is not a directory` (in the case that `*.tgz` expands to more than one file)